# DocuSign AuthenticationApi fails when Login() function called

Tags: c#, docusignapi

My Demo DocuSign terminates when AuthenticationApi.Login() function called. This worked fine for me last week I didn't do any code change to effect authentication. The code exit from login.

```
string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + Username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + Password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + IntegratorKey + "\"}";
                DocuSign.eSign.Client.Configuration.Default.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);

AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi();
LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();
```

After authApi.Login(); the function it terminates the thread and shows following in output window.

> The thread 0x1e68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Can it be something wrong with DocuSign side? Or How do I check the what exactly the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: when hit the line authenticationapi.Login(); The thread 0x232c has exited with code 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS 1.0 was disabled May 29th by DocuSign in Demo.  See https://support.docusign.com/articles/000044869  My application stopped logging in as well.

I moved to the latest (2.1.9) version of DocuSign.esign.dll as well as upped the target framework for my application from 4.5.2 to 4.6.  I'm not sure if both are needed, but it's working now.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Amy this help me a lot. With the above changes, I have included following code to set to relevant TLS. System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;